# Keepalived two master have virtual IP simultaneously

Tags: iptables, keepalived, master-slave, virtual-ip, vrrp

It's really strange on my BACKUP device always turn to MASTER several secs.

I've already search both master have virtual IP simultaneously cases,and all of there solution I've tried, but still not work.

There's two way probably to solve it

1. Priority setting in keepalived.conf
2. Firewall drop VRRP packet make BACKUP device consider it should transition to MASTER

BACKUP.conf

```
global_defs {
        router_id ThinkPad  
}

vrrp_instance VRRP3 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 41
    priority 1
    advert_int 5
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1066
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
    172.16.100.1/16 dev eth0
    #172.16.10.1/16 dev eth0 label eth0:1
    #172.16.20.1/16 dev eth0 label eth0:2
    #172.16.30.1/16 dev eth0 label eth0:3
    }

 #   unicast_src_ip 172.16.100.2         ##source ip
 #   unicast_peer {
 #           172.16.100.1          ##dest ip
 #  }

     notify_master /etc/keepalived/ICS2.sh
     notify_backup /etc/keepalived/ICS.sh
}
```

MASTER.conf

```
global_defs {
        router_id NvidiaTx2
}

vrrp_instance VRRP1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 41
    priority 200
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass 1066
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
    172.16.100.1/16 dev eth0
    #172.16.10.1/16 dev eth0 label eth0:1
    #172.16.20.1/16 dev eth0 label eth0:2
    #172.16.30.1/16 dev eth0 label eth0:3
    }

 #   unicast_src_ip 172.16.100.1         ##source ip
 #   unicast_peer {
 #           172.16.100.2          ##dest ip
 #  }

}
```

iptables setting (and ufw already disable)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     112  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     112  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.18          
ACCEPT     112  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.18          

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     112  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.18          
ACCEPT     112  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.18
```

tcpdump resault

```
root@ThinkPad:/etc/keepalived# tcpdump -i eth0 -n vrrp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:41:38.864030 IP 172.16.100.1 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 200, authtype simple, intvl 1s, length 20
15:41:39.859616 IP 172.16.100.2 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 1, authtype simple, intvl 5s, length 20
15:41:40.862070 IP 172.16.100.1 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 200, authtype simple, intvl 1s, length 20
15:41:41.863060 IP 172.16.100.1 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 200, authtype simple, intvl 1s, length 20
15:41:42.863939 IP 172.16.100.1 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 200, authtype simple, intvl 1s, length 20
15:41:43.864744 IP 172.16.100.1 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 200, authtype simple, intvl 1s, length 20
15:41:44.859805 IP 172.16.100.2 > 224.0.0.18: VRRPv2, Advertisement, vrid 41, prio 1, authtype simple, intvl 5s, length 20
```

keepalived status

```
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 systemd[1]: Started LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor.
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: WARNING - default user 'keepalived_script' for script execution does not exist - please create.
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: SECURITY VIOLATION - scripts are being executed but script_security not enabled.
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Assigned address 172.16.100.2 for interface eth0
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: (VRRP1) removing VIPs.
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: (VRRP1) Entering BACKUP STATE (init)
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), family(IPv4), proto(112), unicast(0), fd(11,12)]
6月 13 16:11:02 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), family(IPv4), proto(112), unicast(0), fd(11,12)]
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: (VRRP1) Receive advertisement timeout
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: (VRRP1) Entering MASTER STATE
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: (VRRP1) setting VIPs.
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Sending gratuitous ARP on eth0 for 172.16.100.1
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: (VRRP1) Sending/queueing gratuitous ARPs on eth0 for 172.16.100.1
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Sending gratuitous ARP on eth0 for 172.16.100.1
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Sending gratuitous ARP on eth0 for 172.16.100.1
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Sending gratuitous ARP on eth0 for 172.16.100.1
6月 13 16:11:18 ycshen-ThinkPad-E470 Keepalived_vrrp[4454]: Sending gratuitous ARP on eth0 for 172.16.100.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `vrrp_instance` name should be identical for both instances. You have one named `VRRP3` and one named `VRRP1`.

Comment: Thx, and keepalived status has updated.

Answer (score -1):

This question can be avoid when I change the Backup device from Ubuntu 18.04 to another Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.(Master device is 16.04,too)

Both the config is the same and I really cant find the reason why make this problem, maybe I'll try two 18.04 version hope this can work well.